# Proving the Completeness Theorem

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In my lecture notes for logic, the Completeness Theorem for First Order Predicate Calculus has been introduced. In the lectures, it was stated that in order to show the Completeness Theorem holds (i.e. that if $\Gamma \vDash \phi$ then $\Gamma \vdash \phi$), **it is enough to show that any consistent set of sentences has a model.**

Can someone please explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 4):

If $\Gamma$ doesn't prove $\phi$, then $\Gamma\cup\{\lnot\phi\}$ is consistent. Therefore it has a model, and therefore $\Gamma\not\models\phi$.

(Note that if $\Gamma\cup\{\lnot\phi\}$ is inconsistent, then $\Gamma\vdash\lnot\phi\rightarrow\bot$, meaning that $\Gamma\vdash\top\rightarrow\phi$, so $\Gamma\vdash\phi$. Therefore, if $\Gamma$ doesn't prove $\phi$, it has to be the case that $\Gamma\cup\{\lnot\phi\}$ is consistent.)

Comment: Reading some of Epstein's book on propositional logic, I think it worthy to note here that this is not a constructive proof and thus does not give us an algorithm or even a hint as to how to find a proof of ϕ from Γ.

Comment: Well of course not. Look how many appeals to the law of excluded middle I made in a two lines answer. Maybe it's worth mentioning that the completeness theorem is not provable without some part of the axiom of choice either, which makes it all the more non-constructive.

Comment: Epstein indicates that Kalmar's meta-proof of the completeness of classical propositional calculus has an algorithm embedded in it to produce formal proofs (or at least he assigns exercises instructing one to produce formal proofs from the proof of the propositional completeness meta-theorem).  Is it impossible to write a meta-proof of the completeness of classical predicate which has an algorithm for producing formal proofs embedded in it?